# Visual Basic 6.0 IDE can not recognize DLL in subfolders

Tags: windows, dll, vb6

Visual Basic 6.0 IDE can not recognize DLL in subfolders
My VB6 project is using FlexNet technology. I have a DLL which is built by .NET.

This DLL is using two others dlls and I put all of them into sub folders, for example `Dongle/lmgract.dll` and `Harddisk/lmgract.dll`

I registered tlb file successfully. And then I added reference to my DLL.
When I make an executable file, it runs well without any error. Nonetheless I tried to run the Visual Basic 6.0 Project via Visual Basic IDE and got the error:

> "-1Unable to load DLL 'Dongle\lmgract.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)0false". It means that Visual Basic 6.0 IDE can not recognize the directory path of subfolder.
>   This error still occurs when I copied the Dongle folder into Windows\System32 or Windows\SysWOW64 or the directory of Visual Studio 6.0 IDE (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98)

I could fix this error by setting **Environment Variables** but my boss does not like this approach.Please help me another way to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After registering (regasm.exe) your .net DLLs in their normal subfolders, when running in the vb6 ide you also have to copy the DLLs to program files\microsoft visual studio\vb98 (program files(x86) for win 64, of course); copy the files themselves not the subfolders, also don't register the files there.

Comment: Thanks for your advice